# How to handle differences in Dockerfile for dev/prod

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Recently started with Docker and I'm setting up a new project.  I have a Dockerfile for a Node web app set up to run an npm script for development which runs webpack with live reloading and a few other processes like linting, etc.

I'm setting up for my production deployment which will look a bit different.

What's the recommended approach to handle the differences?  Two Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 1):

You may be surprised but three Dockerfiles looks better!

- First Dockerfile contains common things for **dev and production** environment, This may named a "my-app-base";
- Second - dev Dockerfile based on "First" image and contains only specific things for **dev** env;
- Third - production Dockerfile based on "First" image and contains only specific things for **production** env.

Let me show you on the example of php project :

### Base dockerfile

We create base image for our project.
`Dockerfile.base` will look like

```
# Set the base image
FROM php:5.6-apache

# install php dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        php5-pgsql \
        postgresql-client \
        php5-mongo \
        libxml2-dev \
        php-soap \
        libpq-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        php-pear \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt

# preconfiguring apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod headers && a2enmod proxy && a2enmod proxy_http
RUN echo "export DISPLAY=':0'" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
VOLUME /var/log/apache2
EXPOSE 80

# configure envarionments
RUN echo "date.timezone=Europe/Moscow" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/date_timezone.ini

...settings env, configuring apache, etc...
```

and  image will named `my_company/php5.6:base`

### Production Dockerfile

In production i want to have container with source code inside, then my `Dockerfile.prod` will look like:

```
# Set the base image
FROM my_company/php5.6:base

# begin instalation
# copy src
ADD . /src
```

### Dev Dockerfile

In dev env i want to have ability to edit source code outside of container, then my `Dockerfile.dev` will look like:

```
# Set the base image
FROM my_company/php5.6:base

RUN docker-php-ext-install xdebug

VOLUME /src
```

Comment: A tree is дерево. Probably not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed mistake.

Comment: Regarding your answer. Can you please explain how do you manage dependencies between these `Dockerfile`s ?

Comment: I will try explain this in my answer.

Comment: Actually my question was about build dependencies. How does your build system know the base image has changed so it needs to rebuild dev / prod?

Comment: all of them Dockerfiles are in one source code repository. And we built all images when handle source code changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should "play" with `ARG` and `ENV`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7.1

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD npm start # the start script can handle the NODE_ENV variable to run a special command
```

bash for development:

```
docker build --tag myimage:development --build-arg "NODE_ENV=development" .
docker run myimage:development
```

bash for production:

```
docker build --tag myimage:production --build-arg "NODE_ENV=production" .
# or
docker build --tag myimage:production .
docker run myimage:production
```